# Windows 7 Aero Snap two windows horizontally

Tags: windows-7, window-manager, aero-snap

As many people already know, there are several ways to trigger Windows 7 Aero Snap feature.
A user can either press Win+{Left,Right,Up,Down} to snap the window to the left or right or maximize or restore. One can also drag the title bar to all the corner except bottom one.

However, is there any keyboard or mouse shortcut to place one window on top half the screen, and another window on bottom half the screen? Please do not tell me to use "Show Windows Stacked" because if I have more than two windows, it will place ALL the windows horizontally, which is not what I want. I want to be able to select the window I want and place it automatically either on top or bottom half the screen.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Thanks for Moab's suggestion, both on recommend WinSplit and updating my question.

I should make it more clear that I'm looking for a software that will do the functions WinSplit provided, but with on screen input, such as **touch screen or pen**.

Comment: Seems they left that out for mouse/keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You might look for software to do this...http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/window-manager-enhances-windows-aero-snap-functionality/

Comment: I just tried WinSplit, it looks pretty promising when use with a keyboard. However, I'm on my tablet PC now, so it's not as useful. Hopefully there is some application utilize gestures to resize the window:)

Comment: You can edit your original post to ask for software recommendations based on your needs.

Comment: There's a similar question here, with a good answer: http://superuser.com/questions/456031/can-i-aero-snap-to-the-top-bottom-instead-of-left-right-when-using-portrait-disp?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to my problem. I use [Windowspager](http://windowspager.sourceforge.net/) to create virtual screens and put two windows I want in a separated "virtual window" then I can ask it to show windows side-by-side.

Comment: How did you get this to work? I get virtual windows that only show what's what's on them. I can't seem to find the option to have it show virtual windows side by side.

Answer (score 20):

The following method worked for me:
Minimize all windows **except** the two which you want to have stacked on the screen, then right click on the task bar and use the "Show windows stacked" option. It will only stack the windows that are not currently minimized. Later, you can restore the rest of the windows as per your requirement.

Comment: Excellent! Without 3rd party software!

Answer (score 4):

You can now use **[WinSplit](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/)** Revolution with its Virtual numpad option: **Options -> Virtual numpad -> Show Virtual numpad at starting**

It will give you a small on-screen 'numpad' (arrow-pad) which you can use to position your windows (works with touch screen or pen as well).

Comment: Excellent!! With 3rd party software!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

No, there is no Aero Snap feature to snap two windows horizontally, stacked on top of each other.

While there might be 3rd party software to achieve what you want, Aero Snap cannot do it.

Comment: I know there is no built in feature to perform this (otherwise, I'm sure Microsoft will advertise this feature). In short, I'm willing to accept 3rd party software that will do what I want.