# How to snap a window to the top/bottom with GNOME?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/268800/windows-7-aero-snap-two-windows-horizontally) for Windows I'd like to snap windows on the top or bottom.

However I can only let these windows snap to the right or left in GNOME 3, so how can I also let them snap horizontally? (e.g. how Cinnamon does it)

Comment: Actually, I think we have not found a usable solution, so I now requested it from GNOME itself: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1240 Feel free to upvote that request.  (cc @nhed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe I'm having a bad day but `gtile` wasted lots of my time where the simpler [put-windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) extension worked just fine.

Just enable the `Move to top` and `Move to bottom` shortcuts and you are done

[image: Extension Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: Thanks. While it technically works, IMHO, this is really cumbersome: First, the default hot keys are sometime taken by other add-ons. 2. I need to remember hot keys for each corner (and these are not intuitive). I cannot e.g. press Ctrl+Up when the window is already at the right side, to move it to the top right corner. 3. It does not support mouse dragging to a specific corner.
But as it _works_ I'll accept it. Further answers are wanted anyway.

Comment: yes  I found the default bindings for the extension for snap up and snap bottom (the ones I was looking for) inconsistent with the default bindings for gnome assume can be reconfigured but I probably won't use this as often.. snappy edge would definitely be a valuable addition...

Comment: I hoped to use this but it's not currently working for gnome 40. For anyone in a similar boat you can use `gtile` fairly quickly and efficiently for this with the keyboard shortcuts (I think these are default): `super+numpad-enter` to open the dialogue, arrow keys to place, `space` to switch grid size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like gTile might be what you're looking for.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the tip. This is at least something, although it does work in a different way and is not that intuitive.

Comment:  what a painful extension - can I have 2 hours back?

Comment: I think it is the most acceptable tiling extension for Gnome. All the other extensions will destroy the current shortcuts you defined and add ugly bars somewhere on your screen.